# What exactly is \r in C language?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int countch=0;
  int countwd=1;

  printf("Enter your sentence in lowercase: ");
  char ch='a';
  while(ch!='\r')
  {
    ch=getche();
    if(ch==' ')
      countwd++;
    else
      countch++;
  }

  printf("\n Words =%d ",countwd);

  printf("Characters = %d",countch-1);

  getch();
}
```

This is the program where I came across `\r`. What exactly is its role here? I am beginner in C and I appreciate a clear explanation on this.

Comment: +1 for "I have Googled...". This is definitely a hard/impossible-to-Google question.

Comment: @R can u explain me the lines  
char ch='a';
  while(ch!='\r')
how can these two lines help to read the entire line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's `Carriage Return`. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2(v=vs.80).aspx

The following repeats the loop until the user has pressed the **Return** key.

```
while(ch!='\r')
{
  ch=getche();
}
```

Comment: i know man that is carrage return but can you explain me what it does in the above code so that i can get clear understanding

Comment: `ch` doesn't have to be initialized to `a`. It could be anything different than `\r`, because it's read in the first iteration anyway.

Comment: your comment is the solution for my problem understood clearly now. Thanks

Comment: what is the difference between Getchar and Getche in the above problem if i use getchar it is not working . can u plz explain me why?

Comment: @GEEKmax this should be easy to find on google. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/37195 first link.

Answer (score 19):

`'\r'` is the carriage return character. The main times it would be useful are:

1. When reading text in binary mode, or which may come from a foreign OS, you'll find (and probably want to discard) it due to CR/LF line-endings from Windows-format text files.
2. When writing to an interactive terminal on `stdout` or `stderr`, `'\r'` can be used to move the cursor back to the beginning of the line, to overwrite it with new contents. This makes a nice primitive progress indicator.

The example code in your post is definitely a *wrong* way to use `'\r'`. It assumes a carriage return will precede the newline character at the end of a line entered, which is non-portable and only true on Windows. Instead the code should look for `'\n'` (newline), and discard any carriage return it finds before the newline. Or, it could use text mode and have the C library handle the translation (but text mode is ugly and probably should not be used).

Comment: @R can u explain the above while loop what it checks while(ch!='\r') and ch is initialized to 'a' what is this?

Comment: That's like saying using MFC is wrong, because it's non-portable. What's wrong with people building platform-specific applications?

Comment: MFC means ?i am a beginner can you  explain me clearly while(ch!='\r') and ch is initialized to 'a' what is this?

Comment: @Luchian It conflicts *Reusability*.

Comment: Testing for (ch != '\r' ) is *gratuitously* non-portable... If you're using MFC, you're getting something that MFC provides... but in this case, you can test for '\n' and it will be guaranteed to work across all platforms.

Comment: This code is clearly *learning material* for someone new to the C language. And someone new to the C language should be learning proper use of C, rather than non-portable hacks. There is certainly a time and place for use of libraries or assumptions that are specific to one platform, but that's in small isolated modules specific to building on that platform, not general-purpose code. New learners of the C language should get this right from the beginning or the quality of their code will suffer greatly.

Answer (score 12):

Once upon a time, people had terminals like typewriters (with only upper-case letters, but that's another story).  Search for 'Teletype', and how do you think `tty` got used for 'terminal device'?

Those devices had two separate motions.  The carriage return moved the print head back to the start of the line without scrolling the paper; the line feed character moved the paper up a line without moving the print head back to the beginning of the line. So, on those devices, you needed two control characters to get the print head back to the start of the next line: a carriage return and a line feed. Because this was mechanical, it took time, so you had to pause for long enough before sending more characters to the terminal after sending the CR and LF characters.  One use for CR without LF was to do 'bold' by overstriking the characters on the line.  You'd write the line out once, then use CR to start over and print twice over the characters that needed to be bold.  You could also, of course, type X's over stuff that you wanted partially hidden, or create very dense ASCII art pictures with judicious overstriking.

On Unix, all the logic for this stuff was hidden in a terminal driver.  You could use the `stty` command and the underlying functions (in those days, `ioctl()` calls; they were sanitized into the `termios` interface by POSIX.1 in 1988) to tweak all sorts of ways that the terminal behaved.

Eventually, you got 'glass terminals' where the speeds were greater and and there were new idiosyncrasies to deal with - Hazeltine glitches and so on and so forth.  These got enshrined in the `termcap` and later `terminfo` libraries, and then further encapsulated behind the `curses` library.

However, some other (non-Unix) systems did not hide things as well, and you had to deal with CRLF in your text files - and no, this is not just Windows and DOS that were in the 'CRLF' camp.

Anyway, on some systems, the C library has to deal with text files that contain CRLF line endings and presents those to you as if there were only a newline at the end of the line.  However, if you choose to treat the text file as a binary file, you will see the CR characters as well as the LF.

Systems like the old Mac OS (version 9 or earlier) used just CR (aka `\r`) for the line ending.  Systems like DOS and Windows (and, I believe, many of the DEC systems such as VMS and RSTS) used CRLF for the line ending.  Many of the Internet standards (such as mail) mandate CRLF line endings.  And Unix has always used just LF (aka NL or newline, hence `\n`) for its line endings.   And most people, most of the time, manage to ignore CR.

Your code is rather funky in looking for `\r`.  On a system compliant with the C standard, you won't see the CR unless the file is opened in binary mode; the CRLF or CR will be mapped to NL by the C runtime library.

Answer (score 3):

That is not always true; it only works in Windows.
For interacting with terminal in putty, Linux shell,... it will be used for returning the cursor to the beginning of line.
following picture shows the usage of that:

**Without '\r':**

> Data comes without '\r' to the putty terminal, it has just '\n'.
>   it means that data will be printed just in next line.

[image]

**With '\r':**

> Data comes with '\r', i.e. string ends with '\r\n'. So the cursor in putty terminal not only will go to the next line but also at the beginning of line

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few characters which can indicate a new line. The usual ones are these two:
'\n' or '0x0A' (10 in decimal) -> This character is called "Line Feed" (LF).
'\r' or '0x0D' (13 in decimal) -> This one is called "Carriage return" (CR).

Different Operating Systems handle newlines in a different way. Here is a short list of the most common ones:

**DOS and Windows**

They expect a newline to be the combination of two characters, namely '\r\n' (or 13 followed by 10).

**Unix (and hence Linux as well)**

Unix uses a single '\n' to indicate a new line.

**Mac**

Macs use a single '\r'.

Comment: Carriage return is used by Macs only in the very dead Mac OS versions 9 and earlier.  Mac OS X uses regular Unix newline as a line terminator.

Comment: Your info about Macs is outdated and irrelevant for the past decade or so.

Answer (score 1):

`\r` is an escape sequence character or void character. It is used to bring the cursor to the beginning of the line (it maybe of same or new line) to overwrite with new content (content written ahead of `\r` like: `\rhello`);

```
int main ()
{
  printf("Hello \rworld");
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the program will be `world` not `Hello world`
because `\r` has put the cursor at the beginning of the line and `Hello` has been overwritten with `world`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon which platform you're on as to how it will be translated and whether it will be there at all: [Wikipedia entry on newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)